# SwiftUI UISearchController replacement: search field, results and some scrollable content fail to coexist in a meaningful manner

Tags: search, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-scrollview

Starting with this

```
var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        VStack(spacing: 0.0) {
            Some views here
        }
    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
}
```

How would I add

```
            List(suggestions, rowContent: { text in
                NavigationLink(destination: ResultsPullerView(searchText: text)) {
                    Text(text)
                }
            })
            .searchable(text: $searchText)
```

on top if that scrollable content?
Cause no matter how I hoax this together when

```
@State private var suggestions: [String] = []
```

gets populated (non empty) the search results are not squeezed in (or, better yet, shown on top of

```
"Some views here"
```

So what I want to achieve in different terms: search field is on top, scrollable content driven by the search results is underneath, drop down with search suggestions either temporarily squeeses scrollable content down or is overlaid on top like a modal sheet.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for UIKit like search behaviour you have to display your results in an overlay:

**1. Let's declare a screen to display the results:**

```
struct SearchResultsScreen: View {
    
    @Environment(\.isSearching) private var isSearching
    var results: [String]?
    
    var body: some View {
        if isSearching, let results {
            if results.isEmpty {
                Text("nothing to see here")
            } else {
                List(results, id: \.self) { fruit in
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text(fruit)) {
                        Text(fruit)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**2. Let's have an `ObservableObject` to handle the logic:**

```
class Search: ObservableObject {
    
    static private let fruit = [
        "Apples ",
        "Cherries ",
        "Pears ",
        "Oranges ",
        "Pineapples ",
        "Bananas "
    ]
    
    @Published var text: String = ""
    
    var results: [String]? {
        if text.isEmpty {
            return nil
        } else {
            return Self.fruit.filter({ $0.contains(text)})
        }
    }
}
```

**3. And lastly lets declare the main screen where the search bar is displayed:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var search = Search()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            LinearGradient(colors: [.orange, .red], startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
                .overlay(SearchResultsScreen(results: search.results))
                .searchable(text: $search.text)
                .navigationTitle("Find that fruit")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works with LinearGradient in NavigationView but does not in my case of     var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 0.0) {. Where would I put overlay/searchable/navtitle for the searchbar to appear?

Comment: It makes no difference if I wire up with overlay.searchable  ScrollView or VStack (or navview even) -> search bar does not show up :-[

Comment: And it was hidden due to .navigationBarHidden(true) I guess I need to shownavbar when user taps on search only but that's another question

Comment: Definitely you have to have overlay followed by searchable - other way round it doesn't work.

Comment: I would attach both to the outside of the scroll view

Comment: Thanks. Do you know whw in my case the nav title shows up but the search field is hidden until ya scroll?

Comment: there is placement argument to searchable which defines this behaviour

Comment: e.g `placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always)` should ensure it stays visible

Comment: Yes, thank you. It does not hide on scroll than. It seems to be all or nothing. It's just a bug on iOS with the .default. It's fine on iPadOS.